# Sorting a 2 dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

wonder if anyone can help;

I have an a two dimensional array which I need to group by any common "job number" element;
Here's an example - I'm just playing with the idea at the moment, The $i is just a counter that iterates through the array results;

```
$galleryItems[$i][0] = 'example title';//the title
 $galleryItems[$i][1] = 'example description';//description
 $galleryItems[$i][2] = 'the client';//client
 $galleryItems[$i][3] = '00000';//job number
```

Any ideas on how to group these toegther, eg so if had a number of 00000 job items it would stick all these toegther, and any 00001 would be group together etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$galleryItemsGrouped = array();
foreach($galleryItems as $k => $v) {
  $galleryItemsGrouped[$v[3]][] = $v;
}
var_dump($galleryItemsGrouped);
```

or maybe that's what you mean

```
usort($galleryItems, function($a,$b) {
  if($a[3] == $b[3]) return 0;
  return $a[3]<$b[3] ? -1 : 1;
});
var_dump($galleryItems);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks - The first brings back the results grouped, but I think the second one looks like what I'm after (keeping the depth of the galleryitems array the same) but I'm getting a unexpected T_FUNCTION when I try and play around with it, cheers

Comment: Apologies, I think the first one is more what I'm after as the job numbers are stored as Strings, and don't need to be in numerical order, they just need to group toegther. If I understand right the second will list by thier numrical order?

Comment: The second will work in PHP 5.3+. In php 5.2 you would need to create a variable function or a callback instead of passing the anonymous function. See manual for usort() for examples, and you should be able to rewrite it. The second will also compare strings, but the resulting data structure will be a bit different.

Comment: Cool, thanks - I rewrote it a little and it seems to be bring back what I need - Cheers

Answer (score 0):

to stick together you have to use php's [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function on $galleryItems[$i]

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll probably have to write a sorting callback function that you can use with usort(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

If this data comes from a database, you might want to look at using a GROUP BY clause there and save yourself the trouble of sorting on the server.

On a more designy level, perhaps consider an array of galleryItem objects instead of a 2D array.

G

Comment: Hi, I tried the group by option, but I found it a bit tricky as I'm pulling from some wordpress plugin tables, and I found I couldnt roll my sql into one statement. I could have a look down that road again, but I didn't have much success before.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of number indexes, use names:

```
$galleryItems[$i]['title'] = 'example title';//the title
$galleryItems[$i]['description'] = 'example description';//description
$galleryItems[$i]['client'] = 'the client';//client
$galleryItems[$i]['job_number'] = '00000';//job number
```

Then you can sort with this function:

```
function sort_by_job_number ( $a, $b ) 
{
    if ( $a['job_number'] == $b['job_number'] ) {
        return 0;
    }    

    return ($a['job_number'] > $b['job_number']) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

usort($galleryItems,'sort_by_job_number');